# Swift: Keeping copies of data consistent across multiple viewControllers & Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm building an app with similar functionality to Instagram, and I'm not sure how to best structure my data for my tableviews and collectionviews. Let's go over the views first.

1. Newsfeed VC with its own array of Posts (newest information)
2. Group VC with its own array of Posts (group specific information there are ~30 different groups)
3. Search VC with its own array of Posts (search result specific)
4. Expanded VC just displays the Post in full screen

The problem is that a user can like/comment on a Post in the Group/Search VC that ***might*** also be in the Newsfeed VC or vice versa.

Currently I am passing an index from VC to VC and modifying the data in the array. This has lead to a few problem where I end up looping over the other arrays to sync likes/comments and then I have to refresh that tableview so the user change in present locally.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient/logical way to store all of this data. I need to group data to be separate from the newsfeed data, and the user can change the group whenever they want to see other posts.

I've never used core data, but I'm open to anything. Ideally, I'd be able to store all of my information in one place with just a single copy of every post. Right now if a post is in a group & the newsfeed I have two copies, one in each corresponding array. I also need to get the posts in order (they have a timestamp and unique ids from Firebase already).

***Update***

Due to the learning curve associated with CoreData I decided to store all of my Posts in a dictionary. Then each VC just stores the keys of the relevant Posts. This way I am only maintaining one copy of the data. Not sure how well this works for performance, but it's better than multiple copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to store all of the post objects in a dictionary and just store the key to the posts for each viewController in an array. This prevented the overhead of having to learn CoreData for the time being, and resolved the issue of having multiple copies of the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use core data to save your posts from all view controllers based on their unique ID, It will avoid duplicate records.

When you pull data from the server, each time you need to save in core data.

After that, on each control, you need to right predicate, which should match with your query while fetching data for particular view controller.

By using that predicate, fetch data from core data, and use that data to display in your view controller.

To reflect changes in each view controller, you can fetch data from core data in ViewWillAppear and reload table OR You can use NSFetchedResultsController to keep your data updated.

Hope this will Help.